# How can I construct a specific sigmoid function?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, functions, asymptotics

The simple [sigmoid function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) $$f(x)=1/(1+e^{−x})$$ approaches zero as *x* tends to negative infinity, and approaches $1$ as *x* tends to positive infinity. But I want to set $1$ and $20$ instead of $0$ and $1$. Simply my sigmoid function should behave like this:
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = 20,$$ and $$ \lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = 1.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try $$f(x)=\frac{1+20e^{x}}{1+e^{x}}$$

Answer (score 0):

For a more general case where,

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = u,$$ and $$ \lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = v.$$

Try,

$$
\sigma(x) = \frac{v+ue^x}{1+e^x}
$$