# How to remodel sigmoid function so as to move stretch/enlarge it?

Tags: special-functions, exponential-function

I have a question similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/925979/how-can-i-construct-a-specific-sigmoid-function).

I want the sigmoid to have asymptotes to $+1$ and $0$ in specific points $\frac{1}{A}$ and $-\frac{1}{A}$, as in the Figure (where $\frac{1}{A}=2$ and $-\frac{1}{A}=-2$).

[image]

How can I modify the curve

$S(t) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-t}}$

so as to make this happen?

Thank you.

Comment: We can easily stretch it to obtain $S(-2)=0$ and $S(2)=1$, but $$S(t)=\frac{1}{1+\text e^{-t}}$$ is strictly growing everywhere, so we cannot have $S(t)=0$ for $t\leq -2$ or $S(t)=1$ for $t\geq 1$ if that is what you are suggesting. At some point I am going to understand exactly what you have been asking all along :)

Comment: But it has asymptotes to 0 in (-2) and to 1 (+2), as in the Figure. I would like to know which is the formulation for the function in the figure.

Comment: The sigmoid is a strictly growing function that has asymptotic behaviour for $t\rightarrow\pm\infty$, not at finite values $t=\pm2$ or any other finite choices. But maybe what you really want is not a sigmoid?

Comment: Probably yes. I'll accept your answer since it answered to my first (mis-stated) question and it is very detailed. And: probably, my question does not have a proper answer due to the motivations you recognized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original $S(t)$ has flexes at $t=\log(2\pm\sqrt 3)$. Now define
$$
Z(t)=S(kt)
$$
for some stretch scalar $k\in\mathbb R^+$, and convince yourself that $Z'''(t)=0$ iff $S'''(kt)\cdot k^3=0$ iff $S'''(kt)=0$. Hence $Z(t)$ has flexes at
$$
t=\frac{\log(2\pm\sqrt 3)}{k}=\pm\frac{1}{A}
$$
and for $A,k>0$ this leads to
$$
k=A\log(2+\sqrt 3)
$$
which makes $Z(t)=S(kt)$ solve your problem. Thus the final form matching requirements for the flexes is
$$
Z(t)=\frac{1}{1+\text{e}^{-A\log(2+\sqrt 3)t}}
$$

---

If in addition to that we want $W(\pm\frac 1A)=\pm 1$, then by symmetry around the point $(0,0.5)$ this simply means
$$
W(t)=\frac{1}{Z(1/A)-0.5}(Z(t)-0.5)
$$
here is a graph showing $S(t),Z(t)$ and $W(t)$ defined this way.

[image]

Here $S(t)$ is blue, $Z(t)$ is red, and $W(t)$ is purple.

---

**EDIT:** OK, I think that I know a function that could do the job, if you want it. In the theory of smooth manifolds, we use so-called *bump functions* based on the function $$
f(t)=
\begin{cases}
\text{e}^{-1/t}&\text{ for } t>0\\
0&\text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}$$
which can then be used to define a function with a graph similar to what you are suggesting here, namely $$h(t)=\frac{f(t/4+1/2)}{f(t/4+1/2)+f(1/2-t/4)}$$

having the following graph:

[image]

where $f(t)$ is the red curve and $h(t)$ is the blue curve. Note that $h(t)\in(0,1)$ for $t\in(-2,2)$ and $h(t)\in\{0,1\}$ elsewhere.

Comment: So which is the final form of your $Z(t)$?

Comment: @Eleanore: I added a litte more - including the final form. I hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer is great, but actually I think I mislead you somehow. I would like it to have its asymptote in $\frac{1}{A}$, so that $Z(\frac{1}{A})\approx 1$.

Comment: @Eleanore: What about flexes then? You can use my last comment to match asymptotes, since they are $y=0$ and $y=1$ for the original function, so by using $Z(t)=a\cdot S(t)/A+b$ with $a=2/A$ and $b=-1/A$ you have asymptotes at $y=\pm 1/A$ if that is what you wanted. But I better wait and see what you are aiming for.

Comment: @Eleanore: Do you still want flexes also at $t=\pm\frac 1A$? This is absolutely possible, it is just a matter of small adjustments.

Comment: Not necessarily. The important thing is that $S(t)=1$ when $t=\frac{1}{A}$ and $S(t) = 0$ when $t=-\frac{1}{A}$

Comment: @Eleanore: Then all you need is the part $$W(t)=\frac{1}{S(1/A)-0.5}(S(t)-0.5)$$ and you can leave out part with $Z(t)$ that stretches the graph in the $t$-direction to match the flexes at $t=\pm\frac 1A$. BTW, I am also not a native speaker, so we may be in *double trouble* here ;)

Comment: I'll update the figure in my question, so as to make it very clear, because -I think- there is still a misunderstanding! Sorry!

Comment: I updated the question :)

Comment: @String I want to modify a sigmoid curve so I got here. I cannot get what a `flex` is. I searched a lot about flex of a function and what not but did not get anything. Can you please explain?

Comment: Is inflection point same called flex?